# Join results from distinct query with other results in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a requirement where I need to select the most recent occurrences of unique_customer_id and message_id, no more than one customer row per message id.  I also need to return the associated data for channel and reason_code, but these can and will be duplicate data.  I also have a unique_row_id i can use too if i need to. how can I add those 2 fields to my current query? (or do it some other way all together)

```
SELECT DISTINCT unique_customer_id, message_id, MAX(date)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY unique_customer_id, message_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add two more columns, and you know they will duplicate the rows (because for `unique_customer_id, message_id` columns combination there will be more than 1 value in `channel` and `reason_code`), you have use an aggregate function on those columns. The question is, which one? How will you determine which channel and which reason code should be selectd?

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unique_customer_id, message_id, MAX(channel), MAX(reason_code), MAX(date)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY unique_customer_id, message_id;
```

Comment: most recent one should be selected